# using Location Services fusedlocationapi in Android service -- Receiving only one location update

Tags: android, service, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm trying my hand at making a background service that I'd like to run when the app is closed and terminate when the app is open.

as you can see in the code below, I have a Toast message that is supposed that is supposed to display in onLocationChanged().  I am only seeing that message appear once.

Here is what the permission looks like in the manifest:

```
<application
...

 <activity android:name=".activities.ChatUsersActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.RequestsActivity"></activity>
    <service android:name=".pops.PopService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/usericonmdpi"/>

</application>
```

And also, here is my Service extended class:

```
public class PopService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
Runnable backgroundCollector = new BackgroundPopCollector();

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;

private PopCityCollection cities;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Code to execute when the service is first created
    super.onCreate();
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    threadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
    UserLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    UserLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Latitude is " + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println(UserLocation.getLatitude()+", "+UserLocation.getLongitude()+"  --->BACKGROUND!!");
    if(cities==null) {
        cities = new PopCityCollection(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        cities.findMyCity(this);
    }
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("pops");
    db.push().setValue("test");



}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(100);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(100);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    threadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(backgroundCollector, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

}
```

Thank you for any insights you can provide!

-T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
```

the above condition will remove the location updates , after first time so remove this code

[`removeLocationUpdates`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#removeLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback))

> Removes all location updates for the given location listener.

Comment: You are awesome!  Quick and easy.  Thank you sir!